# Can I develop iPhone apps under Windows using an image of OS X?

Tags: macos, iphone, windows

I want learn iOS development, but I don't have enough money to purchase a Mac.

Is there any way that I could learn iOS development on Windows, perhaps using an image of OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://www.coronalabs.com/

They have a cross-platform sdk that lets you build for iPHone and Android - it's targeted to game developers.

http://www.buzztouch.com/ is also supposed to be a decent cross-platform development tool